# Java Swing JTextField setMargin unexpected behavior

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

When I resize the window, my custom JTextField changes size. It only does this once, the first time I resize the window. It's related to this line inside `paintComponent`:

`setMargin(new Insets(2, 25, 2, 2));`

Running that command does not resize the text field until I resize the window. After resizing the window, running that command causes JTextField to become larger. Actual size of the window does not matter. The first time window size is changed, JTextField becomes larger and then it stays large until the end of time. I would prefer if the field was large as soon as I start the program, and obviously, I don't want it to randomly change size.

**How can I fix the size of this JTextField so that it does not randomly change?**

Here is the entire class:

```
/**
 * From https://gmigdos.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/java-a-custom-jtextfield-for-searching/
 * @author Georgios Migdos <cyberpython@gmail.com> */
public class JIconTextField extends JTextField {

private Icon icon;
private Insets dummyInsets;

public JIconTextField(int columns) throws IOException {
    super(columns);

    Border border = UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border");
    JTextField dummy = new JTextField();
    this.dummyInsets = border.getBorderInsets(dummy);

    String path = "find-16x16.png";
    InputStream is = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
    setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(is)));
    repaint();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int textX = 2;

    if(this.icon!=null){
        int iconWidth = icon.getIconWidth();
        int iconHeight = icon.getIconHeight();
        int x = dummyInsets.left + 5;//this is our icon's x
        textX = x+iconWidth+2; //this is the x where text should start
        int y = (this.getHeight() - iconHeight)/2;
        icon.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    }

    setMargin(new Insets(2, textX, 2, 2));
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you setting margins within a paintComponent method? This is most unusual and looks very sketchy.

Comment: Source of the code is in the URL in OP. I don't know why he did it that way. I came across that as I was googling for how to paint an icon over a text field.

Comment: So what **exactly** are you trying to achieve? What is your desired code behavior as opposed to your observed code behavior?

Comment: I don't want my text field to randomly change size. I would like to be able to say "make my text field this size", and then not have it randomly change.

Comment: Please consider going into more detail, [explain your problem to the duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and edit your original question with this information.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what more information I could possibly add.

Comment: Please read your question with a different set of eyes. Pretend that you have no idea what the asker of the question is trying to do, what his goal is. Can you extract this information from the question as it is presented? I know that I can't. Anyway, enough from me. I have to get back to work. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comments, if you cut the code out from the `paintComponent` method and paste it into the constructor, you will get your desired result.

The `paintComponent` method for actual painting, i.e. blanking the background of the field and drawing the text. Generally, unless you specifically want to change the way the component is drawn, you should not need to override this method.

Comment: Thanks. If there is a better way to draw the icon over the text field, let me know.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen: if you'd explain exactly what you're trying to achieve we will. Show an image of what you're getting at, something, anything. Note that this answer just rehashes my comment, which is not a criticism of Jimadilo, but just tells you that if you want a better answer, something better than what you got on immediately asking the question, please please ask a better question.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen: I've actually never tried to add an icon directly to an icon to a text field. Do you want to have the icon show up behind the text being typed, or to the side of it?

Comment: On the side, the same way as it is in the link in OP. It works now, I was just wondering if this was a bad way to go about it.